# Setting View Height In Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a layout like this in which I want to display a label above a view and then repeat it below.

Here is my code...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speedLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/speed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/speedGraph"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/speedLbl"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/blueColour" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distanceLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/speedGraph"
        android:text="@string/distance"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/distanceGraph"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/distanceLbl"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/blueColour" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is I don't want to set a height for the two views as I want them to dynamically change depending on the screen size. 
I tried using `layout_weight` but it doesn't like the fact that its nested inside another.

Can anyone see another solution for this problem??

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you clarify it?

Comment: I want them to be the same size but I don't want to set a specific size as I want to fill the whole screen vertically. So I don't want to use 40dp or some other size maybe a percentage.

Comment: @DiscoS2 So you basically want that each group of `TextView` + `View` to occupy half of the parent `RelativeLayout`'s height?

Comment: Yea thats right. layout_weight would be ideal I just get a warning

Comment: I've added an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid the double weights issue with a small trick. You could set an empty `View` at the vertical center of the parent `RelativeLayout` and position the two groups above and below that `View`, something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View android:id="@+id/anchor" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speedLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/speed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/speedGraph"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/speedLbl"
        android:layout_above="@id/anchor"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/blueColour" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distanceLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/anchor"
        android:text="@string/distance"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/distanceGraph"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/distanceLbl"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/blueColour" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also you should use the `@+id/...` notation only when you first declare that id, on the next id occurrence you should use `@id/...`.

Comment: you should use "Space" instead of View as anchor,Space saves more memory and resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the dynamic screen size through  `layout_weight` . But before that you just try  `layout_weight` to the Linear Layout and provide the appropriate weights to the view and textview. It almost solve your problem. Dont use Relative Layout with Weight. weight is not working in Relative layout.

Comment: I have already used a linear layout with a weight, the problem was I get a warning about using nested layout_weight tags saying its not good for performance so I am trying to find another way of doing it, hence turning to relative layouts.

Comment: js lint shows that warning. It will not affect your performance.